# How to replace findViewById(v.getId()) with View Binding?

Tags: android, android-studio, view, binding

By clicking on a button, I can find the id of the button through `findViewById(v.getId())`. How can I replace it with View Binding?

This is my code:

```
fun TastoClick(v: View) {
    val btn = findViewById(v.getId()) as Button
    var name = btn.text.toString().toInt()
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Please do give the documentation for [View Binding](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/view-binding) a look I'm sure you will find it answers your question.

But in summary:

1. in the module-level **build.gradle** add:

   ```
   android {
       ...
       buildFeatures {
           viewBinding true
       }
   }
   ```
2. For a **Fragment** with an xml like `result_profile.xml` a binding class will be generated in the format: `ResultProfileBinding` you will then need to setup an instance for that class as below:

**result_profile.xml:**

```
<LinearLayout ... >
    <TextView android:id="@+id/name" />
    <ImageView android:cropToPadding="true" />
    <Button android:id="@+id/button"
        android:background="@drawable/rounded_button" />
</LinearLayout>
```

**ResultProfileFragment.kt:**

```
private var _binding: ResultProfileBinding? = null
// This property is only valid between onCreateView and
// onDestroyView.
private val binding get() = _binding!!

override fun onCreateView(
    inflater: LayoutInflater,
    container: ViewGroup?,
    savedInstanceState: Bundle?
): View? {
    _binding = ResultProfileBinding.inflate(inflater, container, false)
    val view = binding.root
    return view
}

override fun onDestroyView() {
    super.onDestroyView()
    _binding = null
}
```

3. For an **Activity**:

**ResultProfileActivity.kt:**

```
private lateinit var binding: ResultProfileBinding

override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    binding = ResultProfileBinding.inflate(layoutInflater)
    val view = binding.root
    setContentView(view)
}
```

You can then access the layout elements like this:

```
binding.name.text = viewModel.name
binding.button.setOnClickListener { viewModel.userClicked() }
```

**Update:**

If you have one listener for multiple buttons you can simple compare the view passed into the `onClick` method with your view bindings id i.e.

```
v.id == binding.yourbutton.id
```

A switch statement or if statement may be used to check which id matches the view that was clicked.

Comment: Thanks but this doesn't allow me to get the id of the clicked button

Comment: I am already using View Binding and would like to replace all findViewbyId() in my code

Comment: just invoke binding.view.id and you'll get your id.

Comment: As @benyuss said if you need the `id` you can use the code he showed, and you can remove findViewById and instead use `binding.YOUR_ELEMENT_ID` as I showed in my answer. You shouldn't need to get a view by id as you can simply reference it using the id you gave it Hope that makes sense and please mark this as solved if it has solved your problem by using the check mark next to this answer

Comment: In my xml file I have "Tasto1", "Tasto2", "Tasto3" and so on, with the same "onClick". I don't know which one is clicked. With findViewById(v.getId()) I got it. I can use binding.view.id when I know the id f the button...

Comment: Please see my updated answer. However id probably argue they should each have their own onClick listener but that's just me

Comment: Thanks. In my code all buttons have the same onClick method: android:onClick="TastoClick". I have 20 buttons and I don't want create 20 onClick listener. I don't know how can have one listener for multiple buttons, if their id are differents. In your answer with "v.id" I get the number Id of the button (e.g. 21232111). :( Thanks

Comment: Yes and you compare that id with the various button ids until you find a match as i showed in my updates. If your issue is solved please don't forget mark it as solved

Comment: Your binding.yourbutton.id, it is not working, the id is unknown, but .getId() works on the same binding. What is the remedy, please?

Answer (score -1):

Kotlin

```
val btn = binding.root.findViewById<Button>(v.id)
```